# how does void OnCollisionEnter() works? (unity, c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

as far as i know there are interfaces, and abstract classes. however we don't use "override" to do stuff when OnCollisionEnter happens, and i'm not sure if it's interface thing.

so basically i ask for simple code example which works like OnCollisionEnter. maybe it is interface in the end?

edit: am i right that OnCollisionEnter is an interface of MonoBehavior?

Comment: Unity scans every MonoBehaviour for specific methods (Update, Start,...). Then most likely stores them in appropriate collection so that they get called when needed. It's like an interface but it's not (not public, no interface inheritance), it's like reflection, but it's not (it's a more basic string scanning of the script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Everts said, it's just a method that is only called on a class if that class inherits from MonoBehaviour. It is not an interface where you're implementing part of it, but it's not exactly a base class method either because you're not overriding anything. It does need to use the correct parameter types for each method. You just have to learn about each method as you go.

```
public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} is colliding with {other.collider.name}");
    }

}
```

Comment: oh, so basically its just method that is called on gameobject whenever it touches something. so as i understand there's a unity code on each gameobject where it calls the OnCollisionEnter if there is one (?). i just want to understand how i would implement this kind of method caller. i dont think its that simple to find a script 
 on a gameobject and call the method if it's there without getting any errors

Comment: i also have a question if the code that calls the OnCollisionEnter method is in rigidbody component script, since it doesnt detect collisions without rigidbody

Comment: Rigid bodies detect collision and let involved objects know about it. I'm not sure which part actually calls the method. What you're looking for though is SendMessage(). You can use that to call a method by string name. It will go through every component on the object and check if any of them have the specified method then call it. It's a very inefficient way of doing things though, so if at all possible it's better think of other ways to accomplish your original goal.

Comment: The "method" that invokes it lies deep in Unity's physics engine. The MonoBehaviour methods like `Awake`, `Start`, `Update` etc .. and so also `OnCollissionEnter` are called as "messages" .. kind of similar to how reflection works.